# Sharepoint Search result webpart, property sort list

Tags: search, sharepoint

i'm using the sharepoint search result webpart and want to get a random result.

with REST it's working with query parameter sortlist=[random:seed=1]:ascending but i want to use the search webpart. It seems it's not possible to use sortlist there?